# Detection or display problem with YOLO / OpenCV on python

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, yolo

I need to use the YOLO algorithm for schoolwork.
I have to know the center of any object detected by YOLO, that's why I don't use a YOLO GitHub, because I don't know how to have this data.

I just followed a YTB video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKK2mkJ-pHU&t=161s&ab_channel=Pysource) and copy the code in Spyder (my python launcher).

Here is the code: (I'm French that's why I have French quotes, and a standard English level !)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time


#--------------------- Charger YOLOv3 ---------------------

# Charger model YOLOv3
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights','yolov3.cfg')

# Charger le nom des classes de la BDD COCO
class_names = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    class_names = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Charger les layers (??)
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(class_names), 3))


#--------------------- Charger l'image ---------------------

# Prendre le code camera.py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

starting_time = time.time()
frame_id = 0

while True:
    
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame_id += 1
    
    
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    
    #------------------- Détecter les objets -------------------
    
    # On décompose la frame pour les 3 couleurs RVB 
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.004, (320, 320), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    
    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)
    
    #--------------- Information sur les objets ----------------
    
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    
    for out in outs:
        
        for detection in out:
            
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            
            if confidence > 0.5:
                
                # L'objet est maintenant détecté
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)
                
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
                
                # cv2.circle(img, (center_x, center_y), 10, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.4, 0.3)
    
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        
        if i in indexes:
            
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(class_names[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = confidences[i]
            color = colors[class_ids[i]]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+ w, y + h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, label + " " + str(round(confidence, 2)), (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, (255,255,255), 3)
    
    time_past = time.time() - starting_time
    fps = frame_id / time_past
    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(round(fps, 1)), (150, 50), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 4)
    
    cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this script, on the 'cv2.imshow(...)' window, I can see the webcam from my phone (thanks to iVCam app, with a cable link), but the problem is the following.
I just don't detect any object, I mean YOLO doesn't detect anything. :/

I don't think it's installation issues because I already do it well (I think...), and I can see the version of cv2 on python

```
>>> print(cv2.__version)
4.6.0
```

I don't know if past with iVCam app can cause some trouble or not.

If someone  can fix the problem, I would be really happy !

Comment: What if you put from line 92-96 inside if/else condition block?

Comment: I'm not sure about the if/else block, but if it's the 'if confidence > 0.5:' one line 73, that doesn't work. But I think something's strange, because my window print between 15 and 20 FPS, and I think that's huge for YOLOv3.

Comment: use a debugger. [tour], [ask], [mre]